Fireblock an offset wall
I have a friend about to close on a new construction house in northern Virginia. It has a walk-out unfinished basement with the outside walls covered in insulating blanket wrap. I have agreed to help him finish the basement, since I have some experience framing. I plan on keeping the blanket wrap and building offset walls 6" off the poured concrete foundation walls. Perusing the 2021 IRC (the current code in this county), I see there is now a requirement to place a form of fireblock at the level of the foundation sill plate.  The planned offset wall will be standard 2x4 framing with conventional fire blocking and faced batt insulation.
What do you experts out there use? Is unfaced fiberglass batt sufficient, or do you use something else? I've seen some folks use a 2x8 top plate reaching back to the foundation. I was basing the fiberglass query on IRC (2021) R602.8.1.1 which specifically allows unsurfaced fiberglass (minimum height of 16") If you go with the wood route, do you use a double top plate and toenail to sill or band?

I was basing the fiberglass query on IRC (2021) R602.8.1.1 which specifically allows unsurfaced fiberglass  (minimum height of 16").  I was already planning to use traditional 2x4 as mid wall in the frame. Of course that doesn't stop updraft behind wall, but there is the blanket to close the space.

The existing wall is 10" poured concrete. The blanket is unlabelled but is fastened to the concrete and is about 4-5" thick and probably R-11. In front of that, I was going to frame a standard 2x4 stud wall for more insulation and hanging sheetrock.
